# jQuery нужно ли проверять на существование класса

Tags: javascript, jquery

Нужно ли писать так:

```
if($(element).hasClass("someClass")) {
    $(element).removeClass("someClass");
}
```

Или же просто:

```
$(element).removeClass("someClass"); //
```

Все равно не удалит так как класса нету, а если есть то удалит, вообщем стоит ли делать такую проверку в данном случае?

Comment: Позвольте уточнить, а с какой целью вы интересуетесь? Если с целью оптимизации, то вы практически ничего не сэкономите таким образом.

Comment: Просто зачем писать лишний код, если removeClass проверяет к примеру сам существует ли класс, наверное первая цель: меньше писанины...

Comment: Я снова вынужден задать вопрос: а где вы увидели такой код, что решили, будто его можно взять в качестве образца?

Comment: Да и просто часто использую данного рода проверки и вот подумал, зачем же они =)

Answer (score 2):

Да, проверку можно не писать. `.removeClass("someClass")` сама поймет, нужно удалить класс, или нет. Точно так же как `.addClass("someClass")` поймет, нужно добавить класс, или он уже добавлен.